# Spock How to mock Autowired class' function call within a method

Tags: spring, unit-testing, groovy, autowired, spock

I have a class that I want to test in that looks like this:
package com.something;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
public class ClassToTest implements InterfaceToTest{

  @Autowired
  AnotherService serviceA;

  @Override
  public List<String> methodToTest(List<String> randomVar){
    ...
    String stringA = serviceA.someFunction(randomVar);
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I mock the results from the call to serviceA.someFunction(randomVar) to return any String of my choice when testing with spock?

```
package com.something;
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification
class TestClass extends Specification{
  @Shared InterfaceToTest classToTest = new ClassToTest()

  static doWithSpring = {
    serviceA(AnotherService)
  }

  def "tests-part-1"(){
    when: "something"
    ...
    then: "expect this"
    ...
  }
}
```

I dont know where to go from here. My IDE shows errors with the doWithSpring code I added to the testing class. Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest thinking of it from more of a unit testing perspective.  You want to mock out the spring framework stuff and just make sure that you're testing your logic.  This is very easy to do with Spock.

```
ClassToTest myClass = new ClassToTest(serviceA: Mock(AnotherService))

def "test my method"() {
  when:
  myClass.methodToTest([])

  then:
  1 * myClass.serviceA.someFunction([]) >> 'A string'
}
```

From here, you can look at data driving it or using a >>> and passing a list of the different strings that you'd like to return.

Comment: I tried doing this, but groovy returns a groovy.land.MissingPropertyException "No such property: serviceA for class com.something.ClassToTest

Comment: this approach of injecting the mocked field when declaring the "class to be tested" solved a problem I was having. I haven't seen this approach in many other examples, its really useful.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution to enable unit testing would be to alter ClassToTest to have a constructor which sets the serviceA field like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
public class ClassToTest implements InterfaceToTest{

private AnotherService serviceA;

@Autowired
public ClassToTest(final AnotherService serviceA){
   this.serviceA = serviceA;
}

@Override
public List<String> methodToTest(List<String> randomVar){
...
String stringA = serviceA.someFunction(randomVar);
...
}
}
```

Then in your spock unit test you can provide a mock in the constructor:

```
class TestClass extends Specification{
 def mockServiceA = Mock(AnotherService)
 @Shared InterfaceToTest classToTest = new ClassToTest(mockServiceA)
```

And in each test case you can mock in the usual spock way:

```
1 * mockServiceA.someFunction(_) >> 'A string'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unit testing, then do what @rockympls suggests.

If you are integration/component testing, then include `spock-spring` dependency and look at the [test examples](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/tree/master/spock-spring/src/test/groovy/org/spockframework/spring) from the Spock guys. Furthermore, if you are using Spring Boot 1.4+, you can do something like:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application)
@ContextConfiguration
class SomeIntegrationTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    SomeService someService

    def 'some test case'() {
        ...
    }
}
```

For more on the Spring Boot testing stuff see [this](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i fixed like this:

```
class Service {
  @Autowired MyRepository myRepository
  @Autowired AnotherRepository anotherRepository
}

@SpringBootTest (classes = Service)
ServiceTest extends Specification{

  Service service
  MyRepository myRepository
  AnotherRepository anotherRepository

  def setup{

    myRepository = Mock(MyRepository)
    anotherRepository = Mock(AnotherRepository)

    service = new Service()

    service.myRepository = myRepository
    service.anotherRepository = anotherRepository

  }

}
```