# Spock testing for SpringBoot RestController and mocking of exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, groovy, spock

I am new to groovy way of testing RestController for spring boot application. I have a Controller class :

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/onboarding/v1")
public class OnboardingController {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OnboardingServiceImpl.class);

  @Autowired
  private OnboardingService onboardingService;

  @RequestMapping(
    value = "/service-models",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    consumes = { "multipart/form-data" },
    produces = { "application/json" }
  )
  public ResponseEntity createServiceModel(
    @RequestParam("name") final String name,
    @RequestParam("file") final MultipartFile file
  ){
    try {
      final ServiceModelRequestData serviceModelRequestData =
        new ServiceModelRequestData(name, file);
      final ServiceModelDetail createdServiceModel =
        onboardingService.createServiceModel(serviceModelRequestData);
      return new ResponseEntity<>(createdServiceModel, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    catch (MalformedContentException ex) {
      LOG.error("Malformed Content:", ex);
      return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage(ex), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    catch (ServiceModelNameAlreadyExistsException ex) {
      LOG.error("Service Model Name Already Exists:", ex);
      return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage(ex), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
    catch (ServiceUnavailableException ex) {
      LOG.error("Service Unavailable currently:" + ex);
      return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage(ex), HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
    }
  }
  //...
}
```

I am unable to find how to spock test the above class along with writing the spock test cases for exceptions and checking the desired response?I want to create a test case which throws an error when the method is called and returns the responseentity which I want to check contains the given Jason data along with the desired Http Status. Sample spock test for the code snippet would be highly appreciated.

**EDITED:**
The test Class is as below(along with comments of what I was trying to do):

```
package com.service.onboarding.web.controller

import spock.lang.Specification

import com.service.onboarding.business.OnboardingServiceImpl
import com.service.onboarding.business.api.OnboardingService
import com.service.onboarding.domain.exception.MalformedContentException
import com.service.onboarding.domain.exception.ServiceModelNameAlreadyExistsException
import com.service.onboarding.domain.exception.ServiceUnavailableException
import com.service.onboarding.domain.resource.Greeting

import groovy.json.internal.Exceptions

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import spock.lang.Unroll
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given



/*@WebMvcTest
 public class OnboardingControllerSpec extends Specification {
 @MockBean
 private OnboardingService onboardingService;
 @Autowired
 private MockMvc mockMvc;
 def "controller should return expected JSON content and OK response"() {
 given: 'hello world service responds with greeting'
 def name = "Emily"
 given(onboardingService.getPersonalGreeting("${name}")).willReturn(new Greeting(1, "Hi, ${name}"));
 when: 'hello world service is called with name provided'
 def response  = mockMvc.perform(get("/onboarding/v1?name=${name}"))
 then: 'expected JSON returned and response code is OK'
 response
 .andExpect(status().isOk())
 .andExpect(content().json("{'id': 1, 'content': 'Hi, ${name}'}"))
 }
 }*/

public class OnboardingControllerSpec extends Specification{
    OnboardingServiceImpl service =new OnboardingServiceImpl()
    OnboardingController controller
    ResponseEntity response

    @Unroll
    def "HTTP response #statusCode when creating service model"() {
        given:
        if (exception) {
            service = Stub() {
                createServiceModel(_) >> { throw exception }
            }
        }

        controller= new OnboardingController(onboardingService: service)

        when:
        response=controller.createServiceModel("test", Mock(MultipartFile))

        then:
        response.statusCode == statusCode

        where:
        exception                                    | statusCode
        null                                         | OK
        new MalformedContentException()              | BAD_REQUEST
        new ServiceModelNameAlreadyExistsException() | CONFLICT
        new ServiceUnavailableException()            | SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE

    }
}
```

My service class is as follows:

```
package com.service.onboarding.business;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.service.onboarding.business.api.OnboardingService;
import com.service.onboarding.business.servicemanagement.ServiceModelRepository;
import com.service.onboarding.domain.exception.MalformedContentException;
import com.service.onboarding.domain.exception.ServiceModelDoesNotExistException;
import com.service.onboarding.domain.exception.ServiceModelInUseException;
import com.service.onboarding.domain.exception.ServiceModelNameAlreadyExistsException;
import com.onboarding.domain.exception.ServiceUnavailableException;
import com.service.onboarding.domain.requestdata.ServiceModelPaginationFilter;
import com.service.onboarding.domain.requestdata.ServiceModelRequestData;
import com.service.onboarding.domain.resource.Greeting;
import com.service.onboarding.domain.resource.ServiceModel;
import com.service.onboarding.domain.resource.ServiceModelDetail;
import com.service.onboarding.domain.responsedata.PaginatedServiceResponseData;

/*
 * Sample service to demonstrate what the API would use to get things done
 */
@Service
public class OnboardingServiceImpl implements OnboardingService {

    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    private static final String TEMPLATE = "Hello, %s!";

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OnboardingServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private ServiceModelRepository serviceModelRepository;


    public OnboardingServiceImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    public Greeting getPersonalGreeting(final String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                String.format(TEMPLATE, name));
    }
 @Override
    public ServiceModelDetail createServiceModel(final ServiceModelRequestData serviceModelRequestData) throws MalformedContentException, ServiceModelNameAlreadyExistsException, ServiceUnavailableException {
        return serviceModelRepository.create(serviceModelRequestData);
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878338/spock-how-to-mock-autowired-class-function-call-within-a-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test should look like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*

class OnboardingControllerTest extends Specification {
  OnboardingService service = new OnboardingService()
  OnboardingController controller
  ResponseEntity response

  @Unroll
  def "HTTP response #statusCode when creating service model"() {
    given:
    if (exception) {
      service = Stub() {
        createServiceModel(_) >> { throw exception }
      }
    }
    controller = new OnboardingController(onboardingService: service)

    when:
    response = controller.createServiceModel("test", Mock(MultipartFile))

    then:
    response.statusCode == statusCode

    where:
    exception                                    | statusCode
    null                                         | OK
    new MalformedContentException()              | BAD_REQUEST
    new ServiceModelNameAlreadyExistsException() | CONFLICT
    new ServiceUnavailableException()            | SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
  }
}
```

The console log (I switched to Java logging when replicating your use case) would be:

```
Mär 10, 2018 12:51:50 PM de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.OnboardingController createServiceModel

INFORMATION: Malformed Content: de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.MalformedContentException
Mär 10, 2018 12:51:50 PM de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.OnboardingController createServiceModel
INFORMATION: Service Model Name Already Exists: de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.ServiceModelNameAlreadyExistsException
Mär 10, 2018 12:51:50 PM de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.OnboardingController createServiceModel
INFORMATION: Service Unavailable currently: de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.ServiceUnavailableException
```

In my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) the test result looks like this:

[image: Test result]

---

**P.S.:**

I know you are new to SO. So this was your free shot. Next time please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. a minimal, compilable and executable example, not just a code snippet without package name, imports and test class. You want help with Spock, so please write a Spock specification (test class), show it to us and explain your problem with it. That way we do not need to recreate your situation from scratch but can just concentrate on fixing your test and solving your problem.

You were lucky I just felt a bit bored, waiting for a guest to arrive, otherwise I would not have done that. Saying "I have nothing, please do everything for me" only shows that you are lazy. If you want help, make it easy for others to help and show some respect towards their time budget. They are doing it for free!

Comment: Pardon me for this mistake. This won't repeat from now on and I will make sure to be more precise. Still getting use to this :( ...But thanks a lot for your help, I highly appreciate your gesture.

Comment: Then I would also highly appreciate you accepting and upvoting my answer.